# How to change text style when hovering over text elsewhere with multiple connections in html

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

I'm new to html, so sorry if the syntax or something is wrong.

I have a some html code. When I hover over 1, I want the sentence "This is the first match" to change e.g. color later in the document
I can achieve that with this CSS code:

```css
#number1:hover ~ #match1{ 
    color: yellow; 
}
#number2:hover ~ #match2{ 
    color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
Please hover over this number to see the respective match

<a id="number1">1</a>
<br>
Or hover over this number to see the respective match
<a id="number2">2</a>
<br>
<a id="match1">This is the first match</a>
<br>
<a id="match2">This is the second match</a>
```

However, I have *multiple* connections where I want the same pattern and not just these two. Is there any way I can apply this pattern easy globally in the document?
I don't know if `<a>` is the right to use, but I though that `href` might be a solution, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since it is not a real link, `<span>`would be the right tag. The CSS could be generated by JavaScript dynamic. But why? How many of these connections, do you need? Having 100 line in CSS file is way better than building this in JavaScript.

Comment: instead an id for the match , you could use a class named as the id it is supposed to match with , so you can reuse that class a few times if you have more than 1 match . (i hope that's clear)

Comment: @Samuel, Okay thanks! Then I will write the connections down manually, if that's better :-)
@G-Cyrillus, thanks! I'm not sure how that would make it possible to not have to write this every time I have a connection:?
```
#number1:hover ~ #match1{ 
    color: yellow; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem using Javascript with the onmouseover (hover) event. However, to give the same attribute to all of our desired tags, we need to give them all a common class name.

```
<body>
    <a class = "colorchange" id="match1">This is the first match</a>
    <br>
    <a class = "colorchange" id="match2">This is the second match</a>
    <br>
    <a class = "colorchange" id="match3">This is the third match</a>
    <br>
    <a class = "colorchange" id="match4">This is the fourth match</a>
    <script>

        elements = document.getElementsByClassName("colorchange");
        for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
            colorChange(elements[i])

        }
        function colorChange(btn){
            btn.onmouseover = function(){
                btn.style.color = "yellow"
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```